# Failed to get updates

Tags: updates

Cant update core and apps. Please help.
More information in attach

This could be caused by external (manually added) repositories or a corrupted source file.
E: Repository "http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease" changed the value of the "Origin" field from "" to "appcenter bionic"

[image]

Comment: Suddenly I have the same problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall a corrupt repository by hand and it works fine. Download and update.